# MySQL Group By depending on other colum value

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have table like :

```
word       id
Foo        1
Foo        1
Foo        2
Foo        2
Foo        1
bar        1
bar        1
bar        4
fio        3
fio        3
fio        4
```

i want to group by word, but only for the same id,

the reslut should be like:

```
word       id     count
Foo        1      3
Foo        2      2
bar        1      2
bar        4      1
Fio        3      2
fio        4      1
```

i don't know how to proceed, regular group by is not working

and

```
group by word, id
```

is not working too.
please help.

Comment: well, no, that won't work, since you have no field named `val`. why not `group by id, word`?

Comment: sorry, that's an example of the query (i edited )

Comment: how does your query look like? the group by should work, but this depends on how your select look like. You maybe add other fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select word, id, count(*)
from your_table
group by word, id
```

Comment: what do you mean groups all the word column? Above query should give the result you want.

Comment: thank you, your code is working, it was a little mistake in my code.